# Aura:if wont render richtextfield or text

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I am having issues rendering anything on my button click using the aura:if notation. As far as i can tell it should work? But when i click the button nothing happens.

***Component***

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral newsbutton" style="float:right"  onclick="{!c.toggle}">Reply</button>

<aura:if istrue="{!v.showEditView}">
    <p>TEST</p>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <ui:inputRichText aura:id="bodyMsg"/> 
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

***Controller***

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isError", false)
    component.set("v.showEditView", false);
    component.set("v.errorMsg", "");
    //helper.getPicklistValue(component);
    var action = component.get("c.getCase");
    action.setParams({
        caseId : component.get("v.caseId")
});

action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.record", a.getReturnValue());
    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);
},

toggle : function(component, event, helper) {
    //cmp.set("v.recordId", event.target.id);
    component.set("v.showEditView", true);
},
```

Comment: In addition to the case sensitive, I have had issues before where even if true the IF did not render. I had to literally access the value the IF was using prior to the IF component. i.e. `<div class="slds-hide">{!v.showEditView}</div><aura:if isTrue="{!v.showEditView}">` without the div before the IF the IF did not render. adding the div solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an case sensitive issue, it should have been `isTrue="{!v.showEditView}"`. Look at the [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_if.htm). Always remember everything in Lightning component is case sensitive.